# Como guardar datos extraidos desde una bd sin usar un form?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, mvc

esta es mi cuestion,Estoy usando puro PHP MVC/JS Vanilla/AJAX/Mysql extraigo unos datos de una base de datos basicamente palabras, las extraigo por ajax al extraerlos con js le creo un elemento html y le doy un inner para mostrar los datos bien despues estas palabras seran clickeables a eleccion del usuario y mostradas en otro div, la cuestion es que depende las palabras seleccionadas como puedo hacer que esos datos se guarden en la db sin usar el form? o Deberia usar un form hidden y pasarle los datos por ahi? o como podria guardar esos datos en la bd en forma de cadena de texto? Gracias

Comment: Puedes crear un botón en el cuál le metas una función ajax, y para traer los elementos puedes ocupar getElementByID

Comment: Bien pero como tomaria esos datos al mandarlos al controller y despues para insertarlo en la db... ? con element.value?

Comment: 1. No necesitas usar el form. 2. Debes leer y organizar con javascript los datos a enviar. 3. Puedes usar un objeto XMLHttpRequest para enviar y recibir los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno habria que ver el codigo pero por javascript o jquery, detecta el evento que quieras recoges los datos y los envías por ajax, puedes hacerlo por boton o directamente desde el evento.
Cuando cargas los datos desde la db los debes poner en algun div o span o etiqueta, identificalos para despues recoger los datos.

Comment: Cuando lo envie por POST vos decis que es necesario un name de atributo en su elemento html ? Porque enviaria dos datos, uno seria el titulo que si es un input text y el otro estas palabras a eleccion del cliente... no se si se entiende un poco la idea. Gracias por el tiempo para responder